# Анимация динамичной высоты блока

Tags: html, jquery, css

Добрый день. Есть скрытый блок, который открывается по кнопке, нужно что бы анимация была плавной по высоте этого блока, использовал как `css3` так и методы `jQuery`. Все анимации получались рывками, как это исправить ?

Comment: ну так хотя бы покажите что у вас есть.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/u09x8bez/

Comment: Ваш пример работает нормально. Возможно, нагруженная страница и слабый компьютер в сумме дадут медленную прорисовку, но не на таком простом примере.